# How to get Smooth Effect using jquery when changing attribute of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have written the following code to change the Image source on mouse hover. Its changing the image src but the effect is so jerky. OnMouseOver it abruptly changes the image.

Kindly tell me how can i slow down the effect of animation.

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){


        $("#image").hover(function(){           
            $(this).attr("src","images/pic2.png")
                },  function(){                 
                    $(this).attr("src","images/pic1.jpg")   
            });
        });


    </script>

</head>

<body>  
    <img id="image" src="images/pic1.jpg">  
</body>
```

**EDIT**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MKuvn/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` effects in jQuery :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#image").hover(function(){           
         $(this).fadeOut(1000,function(){
           $(this).attr("src","images/pic2.png");
           $(this).fadeIn(1000);
         });
       },  function(){                 
           $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
             $(this).attr("src","images/pic2.png");
             $(this).fadeIn(1000);
           });                  
       });
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MKuvn/19/)**

[Fade IN / Out API](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I have implemented your code, Its just hiding and displaying the first image smoothly but not opening the other image.

Comment: is there any console erros? have you closed your document.ready? Can you share a jsfiddle of it please.

Comment: I got the problem, actually i have to fade out and then fadein after changing image. Please see my updated answer and demo link.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot :) ..Can i add transition as well using jquery? e.g: i want the other image to overlap it slowly..

Comment: you can use to animate images using http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ... explore this api you will get lot many options. Happy to help you :)

Comment: If you move the mouse over the element 5 times, it will run the animations 5 times, to avoid it add `.stop(true, false)` before the first fadeout.
it will stop the animation, and continue it when the user stops hovering. (it will hide the element while the user hovering until he stops)